# W3 Total Cache plugin chronic message

Tags: plugins, cache

I am currently using Amazons Cloud Front service with the super awesome and easy to use W3 Total Cache wordpress plugin. All appears to be working correctly but I do get a chronic error in the admin panel from W3 Total Cache saying:

> Recently an error occurred while
>   creating the CSS / JS minify cache:
>   Some files were unavailable, please
>   check your settings to ensure your
>   site is working as intended

Does anybody have any thoughts on this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eric,
Is the site working as expected on the front end?  Also what version of W3 are you using?  There have been some bugs reported related to the minify cache in the current release which were fixed in the development version.

Comment: Hi, the wordpress 3.0.1 site is using W3 Total Cache ver 0.9.1.1 and works as expected. The message appears in the admin console daily and currently I am hiding the message with a confirm button click. Do you think I should try to use the development version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eric,**

Updating to the development version might solve the problem but I suggest submitting a bug report to Fredrick.  This will help him in the development of the plugin and help you by determining the cause of the problem.

To submit the bug report go to support in the plugin admin and fill in all the information and Fredrick will investigate.  It usually takes him a day or 2 depending on how busy he is but I know he investigates all issues brought to his attention.